# Problema iPhone y preventDefault

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone

Tengo unos botones que al clicar sobre ellos, carga un texto. Me funciona en ordenador y en Android pero no en Iphone (**me lleva al top de la página**). Este es el código que utilizo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(event) {
    $('#btn-servicios-1').click(mostrarServicios1);
    $('#cerrar-servicios-1').click(cerrarServicios1);
    $('#btn-servicios-2').click(mostrarServicios2);
    $('#cerrar-servicios-2').click(cerrarServicios2);
    $('#btn-servicios-3').click(mostrarServicios3);
    $('#cerrar-servicios-3').click(cerrarServicios3);
    $('#btn-servicios-4').click(mostrarServicios4);
    $('#cerrar-servicios-4').click(cerrarServicios4);
  });

  function cerrarServicios1(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").hide();
    return false;
  }

  function mostrarServicios1(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "-webkit-box");
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "-ms-flexbox");
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "-webkit-flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("display", "flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-1").css("flex-wrap", "wrap");
    return false;
  }

  function cerrarServicios2(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").hide();
    return false;
  }

  function mostrarServicios2(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").css("display", "-webkit-box");
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").css("display", "-ms-flexbox");
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").css("display", "-webkit-flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").css("display", "flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-2").css("flex-wrap", "wrap");
    return false;
  }

  function cerrarServicios3(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").hide();
    return false;
  }

  function mostrarServicios3(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").css("display", "-webkit-box");
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").css("display", "-ms-flexbox");
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").css("display", "-webkit-flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").css("display", "flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-3").css("flex-wrap", "wrap");
    return false;
  }

  function cerrarServicios4(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").hide();
    return false;
  }

  function mostrarServicios4(event) {
    /*event.preventDefault();*/
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").css("display", "-webkit-box");
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").css("display", "-ms-flexbox");
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").css("display", "-webkit-flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").css("display", "flex");
    $("#contenido-servicios-4").css("flex-wrap", "wrap");
    return false;
  }

</script>
```

He probado tanto con preventDefault como con return false, pero nada.

PD: parece ser que si en el iPhone cargas la web y le das a 'modo escritorio', si funciona, pero en 'Modo normal' por así decirlo, no.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías mostrar también el código HTML?

Es muy probable que tengas algo así en el href="#algo"
Si la función la realizaras en JS omite la etiqueta href.